# iOS LocalNotification doesnt vibrate iWatch

Tags: ios, apple-watch, uilocalnotification, localnotification

in my iOS app, there are LocalNotifications.
They are triggered and displayed on the phone as planned.

The same notification is also displayed on the iWatch.
However, no vibration on the watch is triggered. All other apps trigger the vibration.

any idea?
Thanks.